# Weird string behaviour

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to write code that imitates a console. The first run works fine, but from there on the string magically starts with a white-space causing the comparison to fail. When drawn on in a window the white-space is present, but not if written into the systems console.

strContent is stores everything that is beeing displayed, while strCurrLine holds the user input line by line.

```
strContent += "\n";
std::cout << strCurrLine << "!" << std::endl;

if (strCurrLine == "hello")
{
    strContent += "world";
}
else
{
    strContent += "Err: Command is not recognized";
}

strContent += "\n";

strCurrLine.clear();
```

[image: Screenshot]

```
void console::insertChar(char newChar)
{
    if (newChar == 8)   // if char is backspace
    {
        if (!strCurrLine.empty())   // before deleting, make sure string isnt empty
        {
            strContent.pop_back();  // delete last char
            strCurrLine.pop_back(); // ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strContent += newChar;          // add the char to displayed string
        strCurrLine += newChar;         // add the char to parsing string
    }
}
```

Comment: What string starts with a whitespace?  Where does this string come from?

Comment: @BenVoigt _strCurrLine holds the user input_

Comment: How are you reading into `strCurrLine`? Please show more code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter added more code

Comment: Use `'\b'`, not 8. It's immediately obvious which character `'\b'` is.

Comment: Try debugging.  Put a breakpoint on the failing comparison, look at your variables, see what the first character actually is.

Comment: @chris: But then he wouldn't be able to show off his ASCII fluency.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Dude, I just didn't know about '\b' ...

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I'm just used to seeing people do odd things like: `if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)`

Comment: @BenVoigt I dont know why exactly I didnt try it before... sorry clear() seems to add '\r' at the beginning... is there a way to clear the string without this?

Comment: @Der_Scorp: It's much more likely that your keyboard handler is adding a `'\r'` after you cleared everything.  If you put a breakpoint on `clear()` and step over it, I think you'll find it really is empty at that point.

Comment: @BenVoigt after some debugging I can confirm that empty() is doing its job. However, I can only guess that '\r' is inserted after pressing the return key... again that would be weird, as it is working at the first run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I found out that pressing the return key seems add '\r' in front of the string. Using the following code it is removed.

```
if (strCurrLine[0] == '\r')
    strCurrLine.erase(0, 1);
```

Comment: You might be adding the `\r` in some other part of your program, a newline read from `std::cin` is just `'\n'`. Perhaps you have used non-standard input functions somewhere?

Comment: \r is the carriage return, but as it is associated with the new line is may be related to somewhere you are adding '\n's. From your code it is really difficult to determine anything.

Comment: Also would like to point out that removing ALL '\r' characters is a bad idea because (1) perhaps it is meant to be somewhere later on, and (2) that's inefficient to do when you know your problem is only the first character. `char* str; if (*str == '\r') /* Reallocate without first byte. */`